# Vertically fit a figure with caption to page

Tags: scaling, floatrow

I have a very large(heightwise) figure and would like to fit it on a page with its caption, that I place below (document wide style which I would like to keep, and the figure fills the line anyhow, so placing the caption on the side is not a solution). Is there any way to scale the figure to fit the page with the caption? (I amaware of scalebox, but I would like to avoid scaling the captiontext).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\floatsetup{style=ruled, footposition=caption, capposition=bottom, heightadjust=object}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[height=1.2\textheight]{dummy}
  \caption{this should be in text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you just change `1.2\textheight` to e.g. `0.9\textwidth`, or something like that?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : this is a MWE, I use a tikz picture. I could try guessing some height(!) however I would like to scale my picture down as little as possible. And I hope that there is a tex style of way to say "fit this figure (with its caption and floatfoot) into the page bounds". (In short: my actual figure does not have height, and I am trying not to _guess_ the apropriate scaling factor.

Comment: Ah, I see, a `tikzpicture` is a little different, wouldn't have hurt to mention that.  (Oh, and not that it matters, but I did of course mean `0.9\textheight` in my previous comment.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could work out how much space is taken up by your float style and adjust accordingly, or you could just let latex do it for you.

If you use

```
  \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\textheight\relax]{dummy}
```

LaTeX reports

```
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 22.2pt on input line 9.
```

so if you use

```
  \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\textheight-22.2pt\relax]{dummy}
```

It is happy.

Answer (score 3):

Use LaTeX to calculate the height automatically, and scale the image appropriately:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\floatsetup{style=ruled, footposition=caption, capposition=bottom, heightadjust=object}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \newlength{\spacearoundfigures}        % It should be possible to calculate this value
  \setlength{\spacearoundfigures}{124pt} % Include \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip\
  \newsavebox{\figurebox}
  \savebox{\figurebox}{\includegraphics[height=1.2\textheight]{dummy}}
  \newsavebox{\captionbox}
  \savebox{\captionbox}{this should be in text}% N.B. only works for one-line captions add code to allow line breaking and limit width to \textwidth less figure horizontal space
  \newlength{\cbh}
  \settototalheight{\cbh}{\usebox{\captionbox}}
  \newlength{\fbh}
  \setlength{\fbh}{\textheight}
  \addtolength{\fbh}{-\cbh}
  \makeatletter\FPdiv\result{\strip@pt\fbh}{\strip@pt\textheight}\makeatother
  \scalebox{\result}{\usebox{\figurebox}}
  \caption{\usebox{\captionbox}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get `LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 123.86978pt on input line 21.`

Comment: Missed that. Naturally, one would also have to include into one's calculations the space used thus far on the page, the space above and below figures, &c. (which is left as an exercise for the reader --- I added a hard-coded value to remove the warning message)

Comment: A multiline caption will give a bunch of problems. Can you see why?

Comment: Yes, one would need to add in code to limit the width of the caption box to \textwidth less any horizontal spacing around the figure.