# Fill page image

Tags: graphics, landscape

How can I insert an image to cover the entire text space of a page, maintaining borders and everything? I don't want a background for the page, but just an image with its caption to cover the entire space available as texts would do.

I tried in this way. I want a landscape page and I use `\usepackage{pdflscape}`

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}[H] \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.5\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{"figure/estrack map_blue"}
        \caption[ESTRACK Antenna Position]{ESTRACK Antenna Position}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: you want `width=\linewidth` I assume (but you do not say) that `landscape` is defined by the `lscape` package in which case `\textwidth`  is the width pf the portrait page,

Comment: What do you men by 'maintaining borders' ? Dou you want to fill the entire textarea or the whole page including margins ? And do you have some other text on the page. The solution, likely based on ``pgf/tikz`` could depend on the aspectratio of the image.
You could have a look to my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423371, width handle the aspect ratio to maximize the image size when keeping the margins unchanged.

Comment: Texts never cover "the entire space". Your task is difficult, b/c you have a float with a caption. So at least the size/height of the caption determines how high your image must be. In general you can use the lenghts`\textheight` `\pageheight` and `\paperheight` and put them as parameter `height=\myLength` with your `\includegraphics`. Each of these lengths means something different and none solves your problem of possible float margins and caption height. Also I think `\paperheight` is provided by some package and is not available by default.

Comment: Related: [Vertically fit a figure with caption to page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132781/134144)

Comment: I tried using `width=\textwidth` but does not give me the correct result. I use `pdflscape` instead of `lscape` to have the same result when I print the document and at the same time also having a landscape visual of the pdf, avoiding to rotate the entire pdf when you want to read the paper.
 @Jhor: Yes I want to fill the entire text area in order to maintain the rest of the page as the other ones, with margins, page numbers and so on. Basically maintaining header and footer unchanged.
I did the same thing with a table and I have the correct result, but with an image I don't like what I see

Comment: If becomes too complicate I will use the `\begin{sidewaysfigure}` option and I solve in this way and who cares. Or if you give me a solution that rotates the entire page, header and footer included it would be even better

Comment: as I said `\textwidth` is the wrong value in landscape mode (it is left as the original value so page headers (which are not rotated) work. Use \linewidth

Comment: I guess that  "rotates the entire page, header and footer included" would be obtained only by issuing a ``\newgeometry``.
But I don't think that is would  be a goor idea to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution which produces the following page:

[image]
using a `\savebox`, a `minipage` and a simple (e-tex) length calculation. It works with both `lscape` and `pdflscape` because these are essentially the same. But the comment are not clear enough to ensure that this matches the desired output.

Here is a MWE, assuming that the image has itself a landscape aspect-ratio (which make sense for preferring the landscape mode):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\capt}
\savebox{\capt}{\parbox{0.9\textheight}{\bigskip\lipsum[4-5]}}
\newlength{\hcapt}\newlength{\himg}%
\settoheight{\hcapt}{\usebox{\capt}}%

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{landscape}
\centering%
\setlength{\himg}{\dimexpr 0.9\textheight-\hcapt\relax}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.9\columnwidth}\centering%
\includegraphics[height=0.9\himg]{example-image-duck}
\usebox{\capt}
\end{minipage}%
\end{landscape}

\lipsum[6-7]
\end{document}
```

The caption is here a pure text block in `savebox`, but could be inserted as a `\captionof{figure}` of non floating image if we can access somehow the format options of the captions.

The hard-job could easily be recast in a simple macro or environment, but as I'm not sure to provide the expected result...